# Missing documentation or deprecated method in Google API?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

The [reference document](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_query_drive) does not list +queryForFilesInsertWithObject:uploadParameters:, however examples, such as [this one](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/folders?hl=ja), use this method. Is this an oversight in the reference documentation, or is there another method that replaces it?

Comment: I recently noticed the same thing...  the official Google docs for the Drive API on iOS don't include any of the methods which actually insert/update file contents.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with our reference doc generation process. If you do a search for "queryForFilesInsertWithObject" you'll see it actually does appear on the page, just garbled up in the scopes section. I've raised an issue with the tech writing team to take a look.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah I see it. Looks like a parsing error.